# Is there any built-in function like find all in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I work a lot with array in javascript, and I'm stuck with the function `.find()` because it just return the first occurence, I want an array with all occurence if there is many.

Here's my code:

```js
const condition = [
    {
      info_perso: 'Alignement',
      symbole: '=',
      info_perso_value: 'Mercenaire'
    },
    {
      info_perso: 'Alignement',
      symbole: '=',
      info_perso_value: 'Bonta'
    },
    { info_perso: 'Grade', symbole: '>', info_perso_value: '2' }
  ]

console.log(condition.find(el => el.info_perso == 'Alignement'));
```

I want an array with the first AND the second element. Is there any built-in function like `.find()` I can use to solve my problem ? If there is no built-in function, is it possible to you to give me some hint to build a function that allow me to do that (this function will be call `.findAll()`) ?

PS: I use node.js

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter`

Comment: Yep, it's work fine thanks, post it as answer to close this subject

Comment: There is already an answer with this. PS: it pays to just read the general description of all array methods at least once: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#), there are only like 30-40. Especially when "working a lot with arrays".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you're looking for [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
console.log(condition.filter(el => el.info_perso == 'Alignement'));
```